# Using regex in C# to capture COM# from a string

Tags: c#, regex, wmi

I would like to capture COM and whatever number from my WMI stored query result. My WMI query string result is: mbed Serial Port (COM3), but will not always be COM3. I tried to use `Match match = Regex.Match(wmiresult, @"\bCOM\b.*\b\d\b");` but that regex expression is not a success. How do I achieve this using C# and regular expressions?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string wmiresult;

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption like '%mbed% %Serial% %Port% %(COM%'");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                wmiresult = queryObj["Caption"].ToString();

                // Here we call Regex.Match.
                Match match = Regex.Match(wmiresult, @"\bCOM\b.*\b\d\b");

                // Here we check the Match instance.
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
                }
               MessageBox.Show(queryObj["Caption"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should be the `.*` good for?

the problem in your regex `\bCOM\b.*\b\d\b` is, that in your target string "COM3" there is no [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) between the last letter and the digit. letters and digits are both "word" characters, means in `\w` so there is no word boundary.

Try just

```
\bCOM\d+\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?37sfu)

Comment: thank you.  That worked as expected.  Regular expressions always confuse me.  Thanks for the Regexr website.  That will come in handy :-)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match COM1, COM2, COM3 etc... It will not match COM0, but will still match COM10

```
\bCOM[1-9][0-9]*\b
```